# In Unix how do I list from 1 file name to another file name?

Tags: unix, putty

I need to list files from a specific file name until another specific file name. For example I have file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt, file5.txt if I wanted to start at file2.txt and end at file5.txt it should list the file names (not the content) file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt and file5.txt. Is there a way to do this using head and tail and if not what is a good way to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are these files in the same directory? The current directory? Are there any other files in that directory?

Comment: They are all in the same directory. Sorry I am just starting Unix.

Comment: You might want to put some constraints on your question. What do you mean "In Unix": is a python or perl script a good solution, how about awk? or should this be done only with the shell (which one) and common Unix utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls | sort -n | sed '/file2/,/file5/!d'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here. Also where is the .txt extention? For example I wanted to do something like this head 'filename' | tail 'otherfilename' I wanted to go from one file name to another and print everything in between including the starting and ending files(The file names, not their contents).

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l | sort -n | grep -B1000 "file5.txt"
```

Comment: This is just an example. I could have 100 text files and start at lets say 44, but I don't know the index is actually know that I am starting at the 44th file only the name of it.